# Python regex to extract data from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file, with lines of the following form:

```
c="etc etc etc" 124:1 124:1||r="TrNAP etc"||c="etc etc" 124:10 124:10
```

The text in quotes changes from line to line, as do the numbers. Otherwise the format is constant. The numbers indicate the line number and word number `(line#:word#)` of the text in quotes in some other document.

Can someone provide some example regex code to extract the `line#:word#` numbers? Thanks!

Comment: Where is `line#:word#`? Post the expected output?

Comment: So you want to extract them as one string (Ex: '124:1') or separate numbers(124,1)?

Comment: for example, 124:1  is line 124, word 1. I think dlask's answer works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> c = '"etc etc etc" 124:1 124:1||r="TrNAP etc"||c="etc etc" 124:10 124:10'
>>> print re.findall(r"(\d+):(\d+)", c)
[('124', '1'), ('124', '1'), ('124', '10'), ('124', '10')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
(\d+:\d+)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sO7mY6/1)

Answer (score 0):

For the full line with all variables in it use:

```
c="([^"]+)" (\d+):(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)\|\|r="([^"]+)"\|\|c="([^"]+)" (\d+):(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qY9kG2/1